# Apply jquery plugins to loaded ajax content

Tags: jquery, ajax, plugins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Apply jquery function to ajax content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771366/apply-jquery-function-to-ajax-content)

I read the [Article about binding fancybox to a ajax loaded content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536269/apply-jquery-fancybox-to-elements-loaded-via-ajax) via **.on**

Problem is: I need the plugin to be activated upon every reload of the inner DIV.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="page">
 <div id="ajax_container">
  content with selectboxes
 </div>
</div>
```

Here's my JS

```
jQuery("#page").on("focus", function(){
jQuery("select").selectbox({
        effect: "fade"
 }); // selectbox
}); // on
```

The content now needs mouse movement to convert the selectboxes. I haven't found any other working event. 
Moreover, it takes quite long for the SELECTs to be converted.

How can every loaded AJAX content just show up with the plugins applied?

note: the AJAX request is made by another js-framework/ruby

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the `selectbox` inside the success callback of the ajax request like this

```
$.post('URL',{data:data},function(data){
                $(data).appendTo('#ajax_container').filter('select').selectbox({
                   effect: "fade"
                });
});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/rTspR/1/)

As you cant initialize the plugin in that ajax success callback, you can register a global success callback and that may work. Check this

```
$('body').ajaxSuccess(function(){
   $('select').selectbox({
                       effect: "fade"
                    });
});
```

More on [`.ajaxSuccess`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/)

Comment: thanks! unfortunately I can't influence the ajax request. the ajax part is done by ruby on rails.

Comment: thank you for that update! looks promising, but now the complete ajax requests seem to be broken. if I activate the ajaxSuccess via the JS console, ajax requests don't work at all anymore; to try it, I went with the following code:
      jQuery('#page').ajaxComplete(function(){
    alert('ajax');
 });

Comment: Just wanted to comment on the first one: Since jquery-ujs, there are callbacks like `ajax:before` you can bind to.